# What is meant by following line of code?

Tags: c, embedded

Here in a program, I found the following a line of code,

`static tUART  *pUART = (tUART*)UART_ADDR;`

Can anyone explain, what does above line of code means?
And `tUART` is defined in one of the header files as follows:

```
typedef struct               /**< UART data structure  */
{
    volatile tUARTBDH uartbdh;   /**< UART baud rate high register  */
    volatile tUARTBDL uartbdl;   /**< UART baud rate low register   */
    volatile tUARTCR1 uartcr1;   /**< UART control register 1       */
    volatile tUARTCR2 uartcr2;   /**< UART control register 2 */
    volatile tUARTSR1 uartsr1;   /**< UART status register 1 */
    volatile tUARTSR2 uartsr2;   /**< UART status register 2 */
    volatile tUARTCR3 uartcr3;   /**< UART control register 3 */
    volatile tUARTD   uartd;     /**< UART data register */
} tUART;
```

Comment: This is not a good question for SO because it is very unlikely that it will be discovered by any future viewers.

Comment: you're declaring a pointer (pUART) that references an instance of the tUART struct by casting the object UART_ADDR.

Comment: Looks like a memory-mapped UART.

Comment: the line `*pUART = (tUART*) UART_ADDR` meant assigning a pointer to another pointer right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because - easy to google, but it will not help the OP as he/she just do not know C. Some basic language knowledge is requierd

Comment: It's a mapping of the UART registers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

static keyword at global scope gives a variable internal linkage.Consequently the variable cannot be accessed from some other file using the extern qualifier.
Here pUART is pointer to structure tUART. The line explains that UART_ADDR is hardware register address for UART and it assigned to another pointer of structure tUART.

Answer (score 1):

`pUART` is a pointer to variable of type `tUART` and it's static, so it's visible only within a file it's in. 
When you cast UART address like that (to a structure), you can acces specific registers easily, by fields of a structure instead of using `UART_ADDR` all the time.